# Связать модальное окно и компонент React

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

Пожалуйста, направьте новичка в нужном направлении. Есть компонент OverallsForm (форма вывода данных с сервера), есть компонент OverallsComponent (выводит данные с сервера на страницу), есть страница, в которой отображаются данные с сервера по определенной форме. Я создала примитивное модальное окно с кнопкой, при нажатии появляется модальное окно. Не могу разобраться как я могу через это модальное окно отобразить данные,которые выводятся в OverallsComponent. Гугл, видеоуроки, книги не помогли мне понять как это сделать. Спасибо всем откликнувшимся. Это код моего модального окна.

```
import React from 'react'
import './modal.css'
import { OverallsComponent } from '../overallsComponent'


export class OverallsModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className = "btn  light-blue lighten-4 black-text" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}>
     
       Посмотреть размеры для спецодежды
        </button>

        {this.state.isOpen && (
          <div className='modal'>
            <div className="modal-dialog" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}></div>
            <div className='modal-body'>
              <h3>Данные для спецодежды</h3>
              
              <div className="modal-content">{<OverallsComponent/>}</div>
              <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"><OverallsComponent/></textarea>
              <p> <OverallsComponent/> ddbgfbgfgnh</p>
              <p> ghbdtn </p>
              <button onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}>
            Закрыть
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Просто отправьте данные через OverallsComponent в эту модалку. В чем проблема то, я не понял. Если очень сложно можете создать песочницу

Comment: Спасибо.Да. Все работает. Я просто выводила данные по Id, которого не существует. Извините